# Rails and Postgreql Concatenate space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, concatenation

I have an search field for user with autocomplete, it was working but I migrated my database from mySQL to Postgresql but cannot get the concatenate working. When I type a first name or a last name is working but when my user are typing Firstname Lastname (with a space between them) it's not working anymore and cannot get it working or figure out what to do.

That's my SQL command :

```
 @users = User.find(:all,:conditions => ['(last_name LIKE ? OR first_name LIKE ? OR    (first_name || last_name) LIKE ? OR (last_name || first_name) LIKE ?) AND adult = ?', "%#{params[:term]}%", "%#{params[:term]}%", "%#{params[:term]}%", "%#{params[:term]}%", false])
```

My issue is here : (first_name || last_name) that will return correct value when the user type FirstNameLastName so the concat works here but when I try to add the space I cannot figure out what is wrong I tried :

```
(first_name ||' '|| last_name) or (first_name ||" "|| last_name)
```

But none of these will work I found another thread on stackoverflow but cannot get it working and I don't understand why...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea about Rails but how about

```
'....(first_name || \' \' || last_name)...'
```